# Struggling to parse file of structured strings, no headers, no delimiters into a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would love some help. I have some large text files from the Dept. of Transport Website. I'm trying to visualize a lot of traffic data. The challenge I have is as follows:

1. The files are structured strings (200 characters long), with no delimited or headers
2. The only way to parse the files is to count columns and then map to separate data dictionary.
3. The files are large ~30,000 lines for a single state, and a single month.

A example is below:

> S56RP037051181U1N13N00

1. The 'S' indicates its a record
2. The '56' indicates the state number
3. The 'RP0370' indicates the unique ID for the sensor
4. The '5' indicates direction (in this case due South)
   And so on and so forth...

I try and parse these file into a data frame:

```py
temp = pd.read_csv('path', header=None, sep=None)
```

However the parser keeps trying to split up the columns. What I would like to do a character-wise parse where each character in a row gets its own column, including spaces, and then split each row apart by counting of the columns per the example about.

I have tried creating a list of rows using:

```py
fileObj = open(<PATH>, 'r')
tempList = fileObj.readlines()
```

And then do counting of columns but this seems very computationally inefficient.

Can you recommend a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: hey Charles, can you post some of the data here and perhaps the link to the DoP's website with the csv?

Answer (score 0):

Does the code below yield a single-column dataframe, where every entry is a 200-char string?

> temp = pd.read_csv('path',header = None, sep = None)

If so you could run a program to generate as many new columns as you need.  Lets assume your only column in temp is named 'record', where each entry is the 200-character string you referred to.

> ```
> def string_splitter(df):
>      # New Column 1
>      df['state'] = none
>      def state_str(row):
>          return row['record'][1:3]
>      df.state = df.apply(state_str, axis = 1)
>
>      # New Column 2
>      df['unique_id'] = none
>      def id_str(row):
>          return row['record'][3:12]
>      df.state = df.apply(id_str, axis = 1)
>
>      # New Column N
>      df['column_name'] = none
>      def colname_str(row):
>          return row['record][startchar:endchar]
>      df.column_name = df.apply(colname_str, axis = 1)
>
>      return df
> ```

Each block of code in the function above is creating a new, empty column in your dataframe, then populating it with a slice of your 200-character string (i.e. [1:3] slices the 2nd and 3rd character).

Comment: That's really clever. I'll try that. Thank you. I do have the issue that the data frame parser keeps trying to add new columns when it encounters certain characters - i.e " (inverted commas). I'll figure out how to suppress that and then try this.